# How do I assign value of an array element to an observable in knockout

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, single-page-application, javascript-objects

I am trying to extract an element from a json array and assign it to an observable such that when its value changes in a drop down the value of the observable also changes upon selection. The observable must take the value of whichever selection the user makes e.g if the user selects a different driver name then the driver name observable should change. Here is what I have so far

**index page**

```
    function PageViewModel() {
        var pvm = this;
        pvm.loginVM = new LoginViewModel();
        pvm.VehicleVM = new vehicleViewModel();
        pvm.topManagerVM = new TopManagerViewModel();
    }

   pageViewModel = new PageViewModel();
   ko.applyBindings(pageViewModel, document.getElementById("htmlTop"));
```

**vehicle.js => where my actual problem lies**

```
function DriverViewModel() {
    var drv = this;

    drv.driverId = ko.observable(0);
    drv.driverName = ko.observable("");


}
function  vehicleViewModel{
    vvm.regNumber = ko.observable(0);
    vvm.make = ko.observable("");
    vvm.model = ko.observable("");
    vvm.model = ko.observable("");
    vvm.DriverDetail = new  DriverViewModel();
   }

function getDrivers(id) {
    if (!pageViewModel.isAuthenticated()) return;
    $.when(getSecureData("/api/vehicleDrivers/" + id))
    .done(function (driverList) {
        driverList.unshift({ "driverId": 0, "driverName": "Please select a driver..." });
        pageViewModel.DriverVM.driverList(driverList);
        var List = driverList;

        List[0] = pageViewModel.VehicleVM.driverDetail.driverId;
        List[1] = pageViewModel.vehicleVM.driverDetail.driverName;
    })
    .fail(function (message) {
        $.msgbox(message);
    });
}
```

Comment: show your html . you can use `optionsCaption` to hardcode `Please select a driver...` not really necessary in vm. have you refered the original docs http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: options binding works well I just want track the value of the observable such that when selection changes values of observable also changes , however here is my html if you need to see    `

<div class="control-group">
        <p class="help-block">Drivers</p>
                  <select class="input-large" data-bind="options: $root.vehicleVM.driverList, value: driverId, optionsText: 'driverName', optionsValue: 'Id'" id="driverdropdown"></select>
                                                    </div>`

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26311/ . let me know

Comment: @super cool almost but not quite please see the edited version of my post

Comment: you used `vehicleVM.driverList` in html but where is that declared in vm ?

Comment: modified according to your vm structure http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26314/ .

Comment: `function PageViewModel() {
        var pvm = this;
        pvm.loginVM = new LoginViewModel();
        pvm.VehicleVM = new vehicleViewModel();
        pvm.topManagerVM = new TopManagerViewModel();
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87973/discussion-between-super-cool-and-anchor).